# How do I eliminate multiple versions of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I installed homebrew, and it keeps complaining that:

```
Warning: Your Xcode (4.2) is outdated
Please install Xcode 4.6.2.
```

As I learned there is no way to update Xcode so I just downloaded / installed the latest version.

The warning did not go away, and as I learned, I now have 2 versions installed:

[image]

**and the warning did not go away**

How do I now eliminate the old version? I just wanted to update it really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/Developer` location is now obsolete. Xcode now runs entirely from the application bundle in `/Applications/Xcode.app`.

To remove it properly, run this from Terminal:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Although, I've simply moved `/Developer` it to the Trash in the past and that seemed to work fine.

You'll need to go into `Xcode.app`'s preferences afterwards and install `Command Line Tools` from `Downloads->Components`. I came across a [tutorial](http://kennethreitz.org/experiments/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew) for setting up homebrew for new Xcode installations.

Comment: Yep. I've edited my answer to provide the official uninstall command. Once removed, you may need to go into Xcode.app's preferences and install the `Command-line Tools for Xcode`. I've found a homebrew-related tutorial here: http://kennethreitz.org/experiments/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew

Comment: sudo: /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found. What do you do if you don't have a Developer directory, but Homebrew still complains with "Warning: Your Xcode (4.6) is outdated"?